# dc.js: Creating sunburst charts using pie charts

Tags: dc.js

I want to plot a sunburst chart using the dc.js library. Here is a
[link](https://help.pentaho.com/@api/deki/files/1883/AnaVizSunburst.png) to an image of what I am trying to achieve.

If there a way to do this using the dc library? Can I do this by overlaying one dc pie chart over another? Is it possible to make the background of a chart transparent?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do in order to answer such questions for yourself is to search the dc.js repository on github.

There is a pull request for this:
https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/907

It has not yet been merged because its tests fail and there are a couple of problems folks have mentioned in the comments. But my understanding is that it mostly works.

Please try it out (you can just copy the code into your local copy of dc.js if you don't want to mess with the git magic) and comment on the PR with any problems or requests. Thanks!